# Tensorflow multiple inputs to graph

Tags: tensorflow

This might be trivial. I have a model which takes some dequeued tensor `X`;

```
X = tf.Tensor(...)
yPred = model(X,...)
```

Now I want to feed another tensor `Z` at times;

```
Z = tf.placeholder(...)
yPredZ = model(Z,...)
```

How do I do this without redefining the subgraph?

Answer (score 1):

The feed mechanism in TensorFlow allows you to feed a value for *any* tensor (not just [`tf.placeholder()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/io_ops/placeholders#placeholder) tensors), as long as they match in shape and element type.

Therefore, if `x` and `z` have the same shape, you should be able to write:

```
x = ...  # Some dequeued `tf.Tensor`. 
yPred = model(x, ...)

# ...

sess.run(yPred, feed_dict={x: ...})
```

In some cases, you might want to feed a tensor with a different shape to `x` (usually a less specific shape, such as with a different batch size dimension). In those cases, you can use `tf.placeholder_with_default()` to create a placeholder whose value defaults to `x` when you *don't* feed it:

```
x = ...  # Some dequeued `tf.Tensor`.

# For example, a shape of `None` means that the shape is completely unconstrained.
# In practice, you will probably want to constrain at least the rank of the
# placeholder to match the rank of `x`.
x_placeholder = tf.placeholder_with_default(x, shape=None)

yPred = model(x, ...)

# ...

sess.run(yPred, feed_dict={x_placeholder: ...})
```

Comment: Thanks again. What if ```Z``` is actually another dequeued tensor? I.e. not a numpy array or something. Can I feed that in somehow?

Comment: Currently I am just evaluating ```Z.eval()``` to convert to to a np array before feeding it back in.  It seems a little messy.

Comment: Hmm, not easily. I presume that you don't want to dequeue something into `Z` in all cases, so you'd probably want to use `tf.cond()`, put the dequeue op in one of the branches, and use a `tf.bool` placeholder to control which branch of the `tf.cond()` is taken.